# Construct GetMetricData API for AWS Cloudwatch in postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to hit GetMetricData api in postman, i am facing issues (https://monitoring.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=GetMetricData&StartTime=2018-06-19T04:00:00Z &EndTime=2018-06-19T04:30:00Z).
can you please help me how i can call GetMetricData api in postman.

Comment: How i can pass MetricDataQuery format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to POST it.

Here's the documentation on how to construct a POST request for CloudWatch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/making-api-requests.html#CloudWatch-API-requests-using-post-method

Below is an example request you can use. Save the JSON below to a file and import into postman. You will also need to create an Environment and provide `ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `REGION`.

```
{
    "info": {
        "name": "CloudWatch",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "GetMetricData",
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "awsv4",
                    "awsv4": [
                        {
                            "key": "service",
                            "value": "monitoring",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "region",
                            "value": "{{REGION}}",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "secretKey",
                            "value": "{{SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "accessKey",
                            "value": "{{ACCESS_KEY_ID}}",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-Amz-Target",
                        "value": "GraniteServiceVersion20100801.GetMetricData",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "host",
                        "value": "monitoring.{{REGION}}.amazonaws.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Accept",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Encoding",
                        "value": "amz-1.0",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "{\n\t\"MetricDataQueries\" : [\n        {\n            \"Id\": \"id\",\n            \"MetricStat\": {\n                \"Metric\": {\n                    \"Namespace\": \"AWS/DynamoDB\",\n                    \"MetricName\": \"ConsumedReadCapacityUnits\",\n                    \"Dimensions\": [\n                        {\n                            \"Name\": \"TableName\",\n                            \"Value\": \"test\"\n                        }\n                    ]\n                },\n                \"Period\": 60,\n                \"Stat\": \"Average\"\n            },\n            \"ReturnData\": true\n        }\n    ],\n    \"StartTime\": 1581719303,\n    \"EndTime\": 1581722903\n}"
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://monitoring.{{REGION}}.amazonaws.com",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "monitoring",
                        "{{REGION}}",
                        "amazonaws",
                        "com"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "event": [
        {
            "listen": "prerequest",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "listen": "test",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Be sure to find and replace {{REGION}} everywhere